# Create dynamic properties and bind hashtable in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind Row to gridview which will not only contain fields of Category table but other tables as well. So I had properties set for all those fields. But since the columns in the table could change frequently I need to dynamically change the properties as well. I found the following one way to do it (using hashtable). But I can't bind the hashtable values to gridview.

How to solve this problem better?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class Row
    {
        // properties
        public Hashtable Properties = new Hashtable();


    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var st = from c in context.Categories
                 select c;
        var p = from pr in context.Products
                 select p;

        Row r = new Row();
        //List<Row> listrow = new List<Row>();
        foreach (var item in st)
        {
            r.Properties.Add(item.Description, item.Description);
        }

        this.gridControl1.DataSource = r.Properties.Values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Hashtable.Values` is an `ICollection` - but you need `IList` to bind data. Ideally, you really want a *typed* list. Why use `Hashtable` at all here? I doubt you have enough rows to need it...

Instead, use a typed list (`List<T>` or `BindingList<T>`). Note that you can only bind to a single type in a grid. It isn't at all clear to me what you want to display in the grid, since at the moment you are only adding the description, but at the simplest level:

```
this.gridControl1.DataSource = context.Categories.ToList();
```

or (better):

```
this.gridControl1.DataSource = context.Categories.ToBindingList();
```

This won't help you put both `Products` and `Categories` into a single grid... but then, *nothing* will if they aren't the same type. One thing that *might* work is an anonymous type of the common properties:

```
var query = (from c in context.Categories
             select new {Id = c.CategoryId, Name = c.Category,
                   Description = c.Description }).Concat(
             from p in context.Products
             select new {Id = p.ProductId, Name = p.Product,
                   Description = p.ProductDescription });

this.gridControl1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Note, however, that anonymous types are immutable (non-editable) - hence no point in using `ToBindingList()`. The other option is to declare your own class for the purpose, which means it can be editable too.